# How to make Grease Pencil lines using Python?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I started learning recently Python for Blender and I was trying to create a series of straight lines using Grease Pencil.

I came across a YouTube tutorial and I seem to be close but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBtuWImeWf8&list=PL9JHPEJ0b5_azp0ggLj3aQLZPMU6ocy8Z&index=4&t=0s

Code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import GPencilFrame


def init_gpencil(gpencil='GPencil', layer='GP_Layer', clear_layer=True):
    gpencil_obj = get_gpencil(gpencil)
    gpencil_layer = get_gpencil_layer(gpencil_obj, layer, clear_layer=clear_layer)
    return gpencil_layer
def get_gpencil(gpencil='GPencil'):
    if gpencil not in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add(location=(0,0,0))
        bpy.context.scene.objects[-1].name = gpencil
    return bpy.context.scene.objects[gpencil]
def get_gpencil_layer(gpencil, layer_name='GP_layer', clear_layer=True):
    if  gpencil.data.layers and layer_name in gpencil.data.layers:
        gpencil_layer = gpencil.data.layers[layer_name]
    else:
        gpencil_layer = gpencil.data.layers.new(layer_name, set_active=True)
    if clear_layer:
        gpencil_layer.clear()
    return gpencil_layer

def _line(c1, c2):
    newpoints = [c1, c2]
    return newpoints
def draw_shape(gp_frame, verts):
    gp_strocke = gp_frame.strokes.new()
    gp_strocke.display_mode = '3DSPACE'
    gp_strocke.points.add(count=len(verts))
    for i in range(len(verts)):
        gp_strocke.points[i].co = verts[i]
    return gp_strocke

gp_layer = init_gpencil()
gp_frame = gp_layer.frames.new(1)
verts = _line([0.104,0,0.955], [0.104,0,0.955])
strocke = draw_shape(gp_frame, verts)
```

Another code that I found around from:
https://towardsdatascience.com/blender-2-8-grease-pencil-scripting-and-generative-art-cbbfd3967590

Code:

```
import bpy


def get_grease_pencil(gpencil_obj_name='GPencil') -> bpy.types.GreasePencil:
    """
    Return the grease-pencil object with the given name. Initialize one if not already present.
    :param gpencil_obj_name: name/key of the grease pencil object in the scene
    """

    # If not present already, create grease pencil object
    if gpencil_obj_name not in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add(view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0), type='EMPTY')
        # rename grease pencil
        bpy.context.scene.objects[-1].name = gpencil_obj_name

    # Get grease pencil object
    gpencil = bpy.context.scene.objects[gpencil_obj_name]

    return gpencil


def get_grease_pencil_layer(gpencil: bpy.types.GreasePencil, gpencil_layer_name='GP_Layer',
                            clear_layer=False) -> bpy.types.GPencilLayer:
    """
    Return the grease-pencil layer with the given name. Create one if not already present.
    :param gpencil: grease-pencil object for the layer data
    :param gpencil_layer_name: name/key of the grease pencil layer
    :param clear_layer: whether to clear all previous layer data
    """

    # Get grease pencil layer or create one if none exists
    if gpencil.data.layers and gpencil_layer_name in gpencil.data.layers:
        gpencil_layer = gpencil.data.layers[gpencil_layer_name]
    else:
        gpencil_layer = gpencil.data.layers.new(gpencil_layer_name, set_active=True)

    if clear_layer:
        gpencil_layer.clear()  # clear all previous layer data

    # bpy.ops.gpencil.paintmode_toggle()  # need to trigger otherwise there is no frame

    return gpencil_layer


# Util for default behavior merging previous two methods
def init_grease_pencil(gpencil_obj_name='GPencil', gpencil_layer_name='GP_Layer',
                       clear_layer=True) -> bpy.types.GPencilLayer:
    gpencil = get_grease_pencil(gpencil_obj_name)
    gpencil_layer = get_grease_pencil_layer(gpencil, gpencil_layer_name, clear_layer=clear_layer)
    return gpencil_layer

def draw_line(gp_frame, p0: tuple, p1: tuple):
    # Init new stroke
    gp_stroke = gp_frame.strokes.new()
    gp_stroke.display_mode = '3DSPACE'  # allows for editing

    # Define stroke geometry
    gp_stroke.points.add(count=2)
    gp_stroke.points[0].co = p0
    gp_stroke.points[1].co = p1
    return gp_stroke

gp_layer = init_grease_pencil()
gp_frame = gp_layer.frames.new(0)

draw_line(gp_frame, (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0))
```

They both look very similar and strangely both give the same error message.

AttributeError: 'Mesh' object has no attribute 'layers'

Any help or reference to a better method to construct it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Directly after running `bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add()` can be assured the new grease pencil object is `gpencil = context.object`  not necessarily will it be `scene.objects[-1]` . Haven't tested but this is how you can mistakenly get a mesh object instead of a gp... and the same is used in both scripts.